# Get result in the mysql database from different dates

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a mysql database :

1. room `id, name, status`;
2. reservation `id, room_id, start_date, end_date`

I want to display just the rooms that are available between a specified period (eg: `2016-06-13 and 2016-06-17`).

If I try to book a room between `2016-06-12 and 2016-06-15`, and I'm trying to find available rooms between `2016-06-13 and 2016-06-17`, I still see the rooms already occupied .

Here's my query:

```html
SELECT * FROM room WHERE (id NOT IN (
  SELECT room_id FROM reservation WHERE (start_date >= '2016-06-13')
  AND (end_date <= '2016-06-17'))
) ORDER BY name
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem correctly. Are you trying to find rooms where each single room would be available for the whole period between 12 and 15th?

Comment: Because your query filters out rooms where someone reserved check in on 13th or after and at the same time reserved check out on 17th or before. But if I reserve to check in on 14th and to leave on 20th then the query does not filter the room out even though that room is not available between 13th and 17th. The same if I check in on 10th and leave on 15th. You need to code two conditions for each of the start and end date or use the  BETWEEN function.

Comment: Let me just try and I tell you what.

Comment: What I want is that, when I book a room (room A for example) for 3 days, from  `2016-06-16 to 2016-06-19`, if someone tries to find available rooms in 2016-06-11 to 2016-06-17 or 2016-06-12 to 2016-06-13 or 2016-06-11 to 2016-06-18, or 2016-06-11 to 2016-06-20, that the room reserved does not appear on the result.

Comment: Michal thank you very much. having tried exactily what you recommended me (using BETWEEN), it worked!